# How to parse JSON Response Object and display it in TextView

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have a URL and i am trying to POST JSON data to that URL and this URL will return a RESPONSE OBJECT and how to read that JSON and display it in TextView

Tried JSON Parsing using VOLLEY

{
    "isSuccess":true,
    "returnCode":"SUCCESS",
    "returnMessage":"Success",
    "resource":null,
    "errors":null
    }

Will VOLLEY JSON Parsing Technique useful for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Although I didn't have used volley, but it can be works in Java.
First, use a DTO for the convience of Serialization.

```java
public class MyRespone extends Serializable {
    private Boolean isSuccess;
    private String returnCode;
    private String returnMessage;
    private String resource;
    private String errors;
    //getters and setters here
}
```

And then you can use Gson/Jackson/FastJSON/Volley to parse the RESPONSE OBJECT.

```java
//Gson
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyResponse myResponse = gson.parseObject(RESPONSE_OBJECT_STR, MyResponse.class);

//jackson
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyResponse myResponse = mapper.readValue(RESPONSE_OBJECT_STR,MyResponse.class);
```

And you can find the volley version to solve your problem.
http://www.androiddeft.com/json-parsing-android-volley/

Hope this can be helpful.